# Cannot login ssh on ubuntu core 22

Tags: 20.04, ssh, login, password, raspberrypi

After installing Ubuntu core 22 on the raspberry 3 mode B+. I cannot login by ssh. I try to use similar password with my account but not successfully.

[image: Screen image]

Comment: I think password based ssh login is disabled in Ubuntu Core. You should have uploaded the public key to the website during, or after installation for key based login.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct what @user68186 is saying. You need to create your own keys

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "youremail@usedonubuntuone.com"
```

This will generate 2 keys in your private directory. Type `ls` from where you execute the key generation.

And then add the public key to Ubuntu One: https://login.ubuntu.com/ssh-keys