# Fail to login with Ubuntu One to Ubuntu Core 22

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-one, ubuntu-core

I fail to connect from a WSL2 default Ubuntu installation to a RPi Ubuntu Core 22 20220610.2. [Download Link](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/22/stable/20220610.2/ubuntu-core-22-arm64+raspi.img.xz?_ga=2.55898987.1356804439.1670179761-1799466914.1670179761) (and also from any other ubuntu version). It keeps asking me for a password. What password should that be?

```
john@LAPTOP-LUVS8UFH:~$ ssh john987456@192.168.1.134
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.134 (192.168.1.134)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:mMZ72EXUnB3s6fD747EG7KWEVDo7yoYp7+WV/TI+oTk.
This host key is known by the following other names/addresses:
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:1: [hashed name]
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.134' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
john987456@192.168.1.134's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I recall I could connect before, but I fail to understand what I could have done to provoke a password prompt. Also reinstalling the Ubuntu Core 22 on the RPi did not change anything.

- And yes, all my pub keys I generate with `ssh-keygen` in the home directory, I add to Ubuntu One. I
- I run the ssh command from the home directory and directly from the .ssh directory - same behaviour.
  I also tried this command supplying my private key:  `ssh -i id_rsa john987456@192.168.1.134`
- I've even created a new Ubuntu 20 on WSL. No luck.

Any hints?

---

### logs from `ssh -v john987456@192.168.1.134`

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.134 [192.168.1.134] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.134:22 as 'john987456'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:x8gTmBpwcHA4Ig7FwThJiXWHaE7vAIvQVrJoMCl+f3A
debug1: Host '192.168.1.134' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/john/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:7gUhzYDbhkI/yRDboz5U3ROP7ULYNoDJCBGHEu7/dqI
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/john/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:7gUhzYDbhkI/yRDboz5U3ROP7ULYNoDJCBGHEu7/dqI
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/john/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
john987456@192.168.1.134's password:
```

---

After writing the Ubuntu Core 22 64Bit directly from the Raspberry Pi Imager software to the RPi, it worked. See image. No clue why these 2 versions would be different.
[image]

Comment: There simply is no password. The "fingerprint changed" output suggests that either the Pi's IP address has changed, or this is the first time  you have tried connecting from this client.

Comment: @user535733 yes, that is clear. But why is it asking for the password then? Because I have typed "yes" afterwards. Should that then not continue to use the pkk authentication method?

Comment: @user535733 FYI, I install the Ubuntu Core 22 on my private network with a Wifi access. It is possible that the IP changes. But that should NOT have an impact on the PKK authentication, right?

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck on same thing.

The working solution was

1. add ssh-key to account
2. make new installation of the ubuntu core.

I don't get why it is so dumb. I don't get why I have not do any auth on device, just enter the id (email). But such way it works.

Notice, I used to use ed25519 keys, but here I put rsa as is advised at [Cannot login ssh on ubuntu core 22](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412680/cannot-login-ssh-on-ubuntu-core-22). With comment of id (the email in ubuntu-one).

I'm not sure if that matters :)